# SQL - Displaying multiple rows with the same ID

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

Could anyone help with this problem, Im a junior analyst at my company and I have taken on a project. We export our AdobeAnalytics data into AWS and query using Athena.  We have a table that shows every interaction a customer does on our site, as a very simplified version it looks a bit like this....

[image: 1]

I am trying write some code to find when a purchase_id is not blank and then display all the records but for only 1 visitor_id.  I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
webvisits
WHERE channel_visit_id IN 
(SELECT channel_visitor_id
FROM webvisits
WHERE post_purchaseid not like ''
limit 1)
and cast(dt as date) = current_date
```

but I just zero results found, appreciate any help thank in advance.

Kris

Comment: post_purchaseid not blank?!? Do you allow blank post_purchaseid's? Try `WHERE post_purchaseid IS NOT NULL` instead.

Comment: If the intent of `SELECT... LIMIT 1` is to get distinct items, `SELECT DISTINCT...` is available.

Comment: It is not clear what is the desired output. If you want a list of all the customers that purchased at least once on a specific day, you can use `GROUP BY customer_visit_id` and `WHERE  post_purchaseid IS NOT NULL` as suggested.

Comment: Hi guys thanks for the quick responses, I'll respond to the questions in order for ease of reading.

-@jarlh The purchase ID isn't assigned till the very lost row when a customer completes a purchase, before that it is esentially and empty string so NOT NULL does not work.
-@AndrewMorton Hi Andrew I think the answer below explains what I'm trying to do a bit better
-@Guy Apologies if I haven't explained it very well.  Essentially I am trying to write a script that allows me to find a purchase ID and pull up all the data on that one customer ONLY without having to run multiple queries.

Comment: currently I have to run
SELECT visitor_id
FROM web_visits
WHERE purchase_id not like '' 
LIMIT 1'

Then copy the purchase_id and run
`code`
'SELECT *
FROM web_visits
WHERE purchase_id like UPPER('12345481851etc')'

Comment: @klj4v3a, what is special about this single customer that you only need his or her records? You usually want to have analytics on ALL users that are defined by some rule, such as "made a purchase today". The "limit 1" must be explained somehow, otherwise, it is not useful for others.

Comment: @Guy Sorry for the late reply, the script is not to perform analytics, think of it more of a function for debuggin.  For obvious reasons I cannot mention my company or it's data but it is one of the largest companies in the world, the data sets are massive and what I am trying to do is to create script that will allow people in my team to run the script to grab a valid purchase id, pull up all of the customers interactions regarding that purchase id and we can then debug line by line what evar & props are being fired to adobe line by line.

Comment: Thanks, @klj4v3a for your explanation. I still don't understand the effort to find rows where no purchase_id. Find the user_id that made the purchase, and then query all the rows of this user id for a complete log of his actions. Seeing the row with the order_confirmation should not be filtered out, as it will be useful for the users to see it as well to know how far the actions are, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a common table expression `cte` and a join:

```
with cte as (select distinct customer_visit_id 
             from mytable where purchase_id <> ''
             -- if missing values are null instead of a blank char you would write purchase_id is not null
) 
select * from mytable join cte using(customer_visit_id)
```

The (inner) `join` will ensure that only rows with a `customer_visit_id` are returned.

This query will return all entries for users that completed a purchase. If you want just one you can add a `limit` to the `cte`

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks so much for the reply.  I seem to be getting there, the above query is pulling in records which is amazing, it is however pulling in multiple purchase id's is there a way to make this pull up all of the customer interactions like its doing but only pull up the data regarding 1 purchase id rather than all the ones found in cte?

Comment: You can add a `limit 1` inside the cte, that will return a single `purchase_id`

Comment: Heya, that's what I tried and it goes to zero results

Comment: hm... that can only happen if you have `customer_visit_id = null`. Can you run just the `cte` with a limit of 1 to see what value it prints out?

Comment: Hi Nicolas I got it working thank you so much, You solution was the right one but because my works data sets are so big it was simply timing out.  Adding a date constraint of
`WHERE dt > current_date - interval '1' day`
to get the last 24 hours of data only makes it worked like  charm, thank you so much